# Does JavaEE batch survive application redeployment?

Tags: jakarta-ee, batch-processing, wildfly-10, jberet

We are using Wildfly 10 in a high availability system with almost zero-downtime mode. Batch processes perform an important part of the work of our system and there are always running many of them simultaneously. On the other hand, we need to redeploy the application quite frequently in order to apply updates (several times a week).
Batches should survive system crash, but do running batches survive application (re)deployment?
I have studied various resources, there is much information about batches generally, but didn't find that specific answer.
Many thanks.

Comment: By batches do you mean the EE 7 batch API [(JSR-352)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=352)?

Comment: @James R. Perkins - yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

During the undeploy process any running batch jobs for the deployment will actually be stopped via the `JobOperator.stop()` method. Jobs would have to manually be restarted.